# Find the intersection of two tensors. Return the sorted, unique values that are in both of the input tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Hi Tensorflow Beginner here,

I want to remove any numpy code in implementation and only use tensorflow functions. Currently I'm trying to filter out Background Bounding Boxes and boxes with a low confidence score. For that I want a index called *keep* that I can use to keep track of which boxes to keep:

```
# Filter out background boxes
keep = np.where(class_ids > 0)[0]
# Filter out low confidence boxes
if config.DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE:
    keep = np.intersect1d(
        keep, np.where(class_scores >= config.DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE)[0])
```

class_ids is a tensor of shape (1000,) where each entry is a number between 0 and 80 depending on the class (81 classes in total).

class_scores is a tensor of shape (1000,) where each entry is a probability for the class of the corresponding bounding box.

I know that np.where() is easily changed to tf.where but how can I get the same functionality as np.intersect1d() with tensorflow?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to duplicate the numpy.intersect1d example.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([3, 1, 2, 1])
b = tf.constant([1, 3, 4, 3])

# This set appears to be sorted, but that is not documented behavior.
s = tf.sets.set_intersection(a[None,:], b[None, :])
fsort = tf.contrib.framework.sort(s.values)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(s).values)
    print(sess.run(fsort))
```

This outputs

```
[1 3]
[1 3]
```

With a few test examples, the set function seems to give ordered results, but I could not verify that it will always do that. So, you might want to use the contrib function just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
since I'm using *keep* later with tf.gather() i don't think it actually has to be sorted but in my tests tf.sets.set_intersection() also returned ordered results.
Only question I still have is why do the arguments have to be *a[None,:]* and *b[None,:]*, not just *a* and *b*

Comment: that seems to be because the set works on the last dimension, and it does not seem to work on 1d tensors. The [None,:] syntax just expands each tensor in one dimension.